# Google Test: How to run tests multiple times without re-running SetUpTestSuite / TearDownTestSuite

Tags: c++, testing, singleton, googletest

I find it useful to run my tests under `--gtest_repeat` for 100 or 1000 times after all tests pass as a final test to make sure there are no race conditions. However in situations where `SetUpTestSuite` / `TearDownTestSuite` can be run only once (e.g. tests use a singleton class that cannot be created multiple times) during program execution this is not possible.

So is there a way to repeat tests without re-running `SetUpTestSuite`?

If not how would you overcome this issue? I can try using `ctest` but that would make it difficult to drop into a debugger as I think I would need to attach to the process being run by `ctest` somehow.

Note: I can use any version of googletest as needed.

Comment: Do you you want to run specific tests repeatedly with the same Setup conditions, but different parameter sets? Sounds a bit like you're trying to address an xy-problem here, normally what you describe isn't _"an issue"_. Clarify the exact behavior you're looking for in your question please, best with a [mcve] for the test case structure you have.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In general I find it useful to run my tests for 100 or 1000 times after all tests pass as a final test to make sure there are no race conditions. But the SetUpTestSuite can only be run once as mentioned

Comment: You should probably try to mock out the interfaces, which may cause a deadlock situation, set your expectations at the mocked interface, and find if your accesses to it are all in orders you expect them to be. Way easier than trying to provoke the problem by cyclic load. Generally, you should take as a rule of thumb: Never try to test uncertanies.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Are you saying `--gtest_repeat` is a useless feature and should never be used?

Comment: @pooya13 Let me add my two cents here. `--gtest_repeat` is usefull as well as `SetUpTestSuite` and `SetUp`. They exist to guarantee that initialization is unified for all tests of certain fixture. Usually we also are interested in avoiding situations where some tests are affecting other tests environment. In your case, singlton will be common and may cause some issues. I would suggest to avoid it. But if you really want to have some hight-level setup - just provide custom main function with your setup and `RUN_ALL_TESTS()`

Comment: @pooya13 What is the reason not to use loop in your test body?

Comment: @ElvisOric I didn't want to create extra work for myself in case this was possible. Also I like to solve a problem once. There might be other cases where there are some non re-runable code in SetUpTestSuite. I don't want to have to re-factor the code for each case I encounter in my career. And saying use a sanitizer instead isn't an answer. I find `gtest_repeat` useful and I am sure I am not the only one or the developers of gtest would not have added such option.